# Why does transition not work for a button?

Tags: html, css, transition

The code looks completely normal and working, yet behaves as if all `transition`s are commented out.

Here is the code i currently have for the button:

```css
.button {
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 16px 38px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #0000;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.button:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

, yet it's color isn't animated on hover. It's just an instant transition. Why?

I tried to remove `all`, i tried to swap `500ms` for `0.5s`, and i tried to add `linear`. Nothing changed.

Comment: Please provide minimal example, because your CSS is working: https://jsfiddle.net/9x3wqf8a/

Comment: @Justinas My problem was that my styles were applied to an <a>, which wasn't wrapped in anything. The problem is fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through my code, and realised, that `.button` was an `<a>` tag, and transition doesn't work for `<a>`, i guess. The code was like so:

```html
<a href=# class=button>Click me!</a>
```

The problem is now fixed, by changing the code to this:

```html
<a href=#><div class=button>Click me!</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here basically transition is expected to work on time of changing color on hover.
I just modified it to 2000ms just for you to realize thats its working.

```css
.button {
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 16px 38px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #0000;
  transition: all 2000ms;
}
.button:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Why does transition not work for a button? -->
   
</head>
<body>
<button class="button">
    test
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and another possibility in your case might be you are expecting it to work on tag but defined it as a class (I am not sure, and also not considering you as dumb)

but in first Attempt I did the same while trying.

Thanks.
Let me know if it worked

Comment: I had <a class=button>. That was the problem

Comment: Thanks for informing
Actually I wrote it earlier but I had to wait for 30 minutes as I already answered another question
Best luck.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet of your code. I added some HTML markup for making it work.

It functions perfectly here.

```css
.button {
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 16px 38px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #0000;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.button:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="button"> Click me! </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe there are parents impacting the button. Should i send full code?

Comment: They were, but not in a way expected. The styles were actually going to the <a> tag. I decided to wrap it in a <div>, and send those styles to the <div>, not the <a>. It worked!

Comment: I am currently using the animate on scroll library, and when i moved the `data-aos` attribute from a to div, the problem returned. WHY??

Comment: ok i got around that too, by adding another wrapping <div> around the button, and giving AOS to it.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to use a `button` tag instead of a hyperlink. If you are not redirecting to another page and it is just an action on the DOM, you should keep a button element.

Comment: I am making a team project on the programming courses, I am the leader of the team, and everyone in our team took one part. I did not make the part in which the bug above is present, and I don't really wanna edit others' parts too much. Just small edits for small bugs.